# Channel Videos not outputting entry data

Tags: channel-videos

I'm trying to load videos in a standard channel but the videos are not outputting

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="videos" disable="categories|category_fields|member_data|pagination|trackbacks" limit="1"}
    {exp:channel_videos:videos entry_id="{entry_id}" limit="1"}
      {video:service_id}//not working
      {video:embed_code}//not working
    {/exp:channel_videos:videos}
    {page_content_video}//working
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Version 3.2.0, EE 2.10.1

Comment: What is the field name for Channel Videos in that channel?

Comment: The video field is {youtube_video}, I've used it without the field name before and it worked fine